# validation in asp.net using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var msg;
    function req1(form)
    {

    if (form.textbox1.value == "" || form.textbox2.value == "")
    {   
       msg= "Please Enter Username And Password";
       return false; 
    }
    else
    {
         return true;
    }

}

    </script>
```

This is my javascript and i want to use it in asp.net form..so hw can i saw error msg in defalt.aspx page...or hw can i use return value(like true or false)in asp.net

Answer (score 3):

You could use a requiredfieldvalidator for both textbox1 and textbox2 or if you need to validate them at the same time you can use a customvalidator and hookup your clientside javascript like done here:
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewD27B15B4-71A4-4258-81EE-9445FAA9F634.htm

if you need to hard reference your serverside textboxes make sure you use <%= textbox1.ClientID %> in your javascript.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET provides the **CustomValidator** control with which you can validate multiple controls on the client and serverside with custom validation logic.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx for a small example.

Answer (score 1):

thnkx i gt solution frm another user...

function vali() 

        {
            if (document.getElementById("").value == "") {
                var m = document.getElementById("");
                m.innerHTML=  "Please Enter the Name First";
                return false;

            }
            else
             m = document.getElementById("");
                m.innerHTML="";
                return true;

            }

```
<asp:Label ID="L1" runat="server" Text="Name"/>
<br />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="T1" runat="server" />
<br/>
<br/>


<asp:Button ID="B1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return vali()" />
<br/>



</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the submit button add this attribute

```
onclientclick="req1(document.form[0])"
```

This will call the clientside javascript before submitting to the server.